# Remove white spaces from string by using character array

Tags: java

```
public class RemoveSpaceFromString {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str="";
        System.out.println("enter the string");
        str=s1.nextLine();
        int l=str.length();
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(ch[i]==' ')
            {
                for(int k=i;k<l-1;k++)
                {
                    ch[k]=ch[k+1];
                }
                l--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        String str2=new String(ch);
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
}
```

> ouptput :

```
enter the string
my name is abc
mynameisabcccc
```

how to remove the extra 'c' from the end

Comment: The question in title doesnt match the question in the post. Do you wanna remove whitespace or the `c`?

Comment: What's wrong with using `str.replaceAll()`...?

Comment: Do you have to work on char array? String class provides `replace` method which does what you want.

Comment: @cricket_007 Who said anything about `replaceAll` being wrong? But, first of all, `replaceAll` doesn't do "trimming" by definition.

Comment: @Pshemo `replace` replaces a character, which is not the same as trimming.

Comment: @Dan no one. I was asking why it's not used

Comment: @Daniel There are two `replace` methods.... (and I am not counting `replaceAll` nor `replaceFirst`).

Comment: Anyways... The problem is clearly that the last index of the array is never cleared because `if(ch[i]==' ')` will be false and the loop exits

Comment: Delete the `forloop` and before `char ch[]=str.toCharArray();` do `str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");`.

Comment: @Sedrick `replaceAll` uses regex. Your example doesn't need that, `replace(" ", "")` will do the same (it also replaces *all* occurrences of `" "` with `""` despite the lack of `All` suffix).

Comment: @Dan Are you reading the code or only the output?? Trimming is only necessary  because the logic of the loop is wrong

Comment: @Pshemo, after reading the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you are correct.

Comment: @chetan if you've found any answer helpful, please accept one answer!

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
str = s1.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");;
```

I saw that @cricket already pointed that out in the comments of this question!
He also suggested using regex like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");   // for only one white space
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");  // for multiple white spaces
```

But to answer your original question how to remove white spaces from a string by using a character array:

In you original example you shift each char-element to the right, but the last element always stays the same! So if you want to get the String again of this char-array, you would have to decrement the length by the number it got smaller (due to the removed white spaces)!

Here's the code (look at the penultimate line (the second last line)):

```
    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter the string");
    String str=s1.nextLine();
    int l=str.length();

    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();


    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]==' ')
        {
            for(int k=i;k<l-1;k++)
            {
                ch[k]=ch[k+1];
            }
            l--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    String str2=new String(ch,0,l);
    System.out.println(str2);
```

Comment: ...or `str = s1.nextLine().replace(" ", "");` since we don't really need regex syntax support.

Comment: But assuming multiple spaces are possible `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` is more efficient

Comment: `ch.length-(ch.length-l)` or just `l`

Comment: @Nahuel Haha yes I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just instead of

```
String str2 = new String(ch);
```

do

```
String str2 = new String(ch, 0, l);
```

Or reduce all to

```
String str2 = str.replace(" ", "");
```